# How to deploy and test our Xamarin.UITests in Xamarin.TestCloud from TeamFoundationServer?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio, xamarin-test-cloud, xamarin.uitest

I have Developed Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Droid projects in VisualStudio on Windows Machine also connected to Mac system for iOS execution (using TFS). Now I want to write and Run the Tests Xamarin.UITests for both iOS and Android. Could you please explain me that How can I write the Tests and Run for Xamarin.UITests for iOS.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new project for UITest for both iOS and Android.
2. Write UI scripts manually or install Xamarin test recorder.
3. If using Xamarin test recorder, you can chose your app and hit record and work on simulator. It will record and write the UIScript for you.

4.Under view-> select Unit test pad and from there, select your ui project and right click n publish over xamarin test cloud.

Click [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/uitest/) for more info